# Best data structure in Javascript to access nested elements by index?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, nested

I want to create a form of sorts that displays questions that the user can navigate to access other answers/questions. Depending on the answer, it will display another question/answer.

Let's say I have:

```
var json = 
     {
      "Did you restart the computer?": [
        {
          "Yes": [
            {
              "Is the software running?": [
                {
                  "Yes": "Cannot help",
                  "No": "Open it"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "No": "Please restart it"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Is there a data structure that lets me access the option Yes/No by index? For example, doing json[0][0] or json[0][1].

Let's say the user selects Yes on the first set of options. I know I can access the keys by doing

```
Object.keys(json["Did you restart the computer?"][0]["Yes"][0])
>> ['Is the software running?']
```

And if the user selects Yes again, I know I can access the keys by doing

```
Object.keys(json["Did you restart the computer?"][0]["Yes"][0]["Is the software connected to the server?"][0])
>> (2) ['Yes', 'No']
```

But this seems somehow cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this so I can access keys/values using indexes (ex. json[0][0][1])?

Comment: use a `set` instead of an array

Comment: What is it that is cumbersome, for you? If you switch to an index-based system then you lose the context in each access. How do you plan on matching the indexes to the questions? What happens if the questions need to change?

Comment: @KyoheiKaneko If the question needs to change it's changed on the json file. Well, that is why I am asking. I want to be able to access the keys by index, then retrieve the values.

Comment: This looks like sequencing rules in a knowledge base. This problem is brilliantly solved by using a level 1 Inference engine (not complicated to create and use, very efficient and saving a lot of time in maintenance).

Comment: @ehtio Ok, I must have misunderstood you somewhere. In your example, you show the question "Did you restart the computer?" as a *key*. And it sounded like you wanted to be able to do `json[0]`, instead of `json["Did you restart the computer?"]`. What I'm asking is how do you know 0, means "Did you restart the computer?" in this context? If you need to read the value of "Did you restart the computer?" from the JSON, then add a key:value pair to the JSON, so that 0:<question>

Comment: I think before deciding on the data structure you should tell us what your application state should contain

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean for application state? Sorry if it's a dumb question but after googling it I am even more confused

Comment: @ehtio How does your application know which question to currently display? Does it remember which questions were already asked? Does it record the answers? Which data are you storing as the state of your application?

Comment: @ehtio I updated the answer based on Bergi's comment

Comment: @Bergi, good question. I guess mplungjan answered this for me thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update due to Bergi's comment. No need for Arrays, just use Yes and No as key

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const questionElement = document.getElementById('question');
  const yesBtn = document.getElementById('yesBtn');
  const noBtn = document.getElementById('noBtn');

  let currentStep = paths;

  const updateQuestion = () => {
    const isFinalAnswer = typeof currentStep === 'string';
    questionElement.innerHTML = isFinalAnswer ? currentStep : Object.keys(currentStep)[0];
    yesBtn.hidden = isFinalAnswer;
    noBtn.hidden = isFinalAnswer;
  };

  document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'yesBtn' || e.target.id === 'noBtn') {
      const response = e.target.id === 'yesBtn' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
      const question = Object.keys(currentStep)[0];

      if (currentStep[question] && currentStep[question][response]) {
        currentStep = currentStep[question][response];
        updateQuestion();
      }
    }
  });

  updateQuestion();
});
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#question {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <button class="btn" id="yesBtn" hidden>Yes</button>
  <button class="btn" id="noBtn" hidden>No</button>
</div>

<script>
  const paths = {
    "Did you restart the computer?": {
      "Yes": {
        "Is the software running?": {
          "Yes": "Cannot help",
          "No": "Open it"
        }
      },
      "No": "Please restart it"
    }
  };
</script>
```

Old answer:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const questionElement = document.getElementById('question');

  let currentStep = paths[0]; // start

  const updateQuestion = () => {
    const isString = typeof currentStep === 'string';
    questionElement.innerHTML = isString ? currentStep : currentStep.question;
    yesBtn.hidden = isString;
    noBtn.hidden = isString;
  };

  document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const which = e.target.id === 'yesBtn' ? 0 : 1
    if (currentStep.answers && currentStep.answers[which]) {
      const next = currentStep.answers[which].next;    
      currentStep = Array.isArray(next) ? next[0] : next;
      updateQuestion();
    }
  });
  updateQuestion();
});
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#question {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <button class="btn" id="yesBtn" hidden>Yes</button>
  <button class="btn" id="noBtn" hidden>No</button>
</div>

<script>
  const paths = [{
    "question": "Did you restart the computer?",
    "answers": [{
        "response": "Yes",
        "next": [{
          "question": "Is the software running?",
          "answers": [{
              "response": "Yes",
              "next": "Cannot help"
            },
            {
              "response": "No",
              "next": "Open it"
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "response": "No",
        "next": "Please restart it"
      }
    ]
  }];
</script>
```

Comment: Like Djave's answer, I like the approach. Thank you for taking the time to create a runnable snippet! I guess this can be the right thing to do, and it will make it somehow more readable and easy to follow.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer due to having a runnable snippet and a more suitable structure. But Djave's answer was quite on point too.

Comment: Why are `path` and `next` arrays?

Comment: @Bergi Because I went down an array path to handle more questions/variations, but of course it is not necessary in a Yes/No situation. Updated to a much simpler script and format

Answer (score 1):

I should preface this by saying, I don't think it is a very good question for StackOverflow (it is a good question, but to answer it you may get very opinion based responses — which StackOverflow is often not about).

You can access objects by keys, if you want to use indexes the simplest thing is to use an array, and also remove the text element from your data structure. It could be that you use a structure more like this:

```
const options = [
  {
    type: "question",
    text: "Have you done this?",
    yes: {
      text: "Yes",
      options: [{
        type: "question",
         text: "Is the software running?",
         yes: {
           text: "Yes",
           options: [{
             type: "message",
             text: "Can't help",
           }]
         },
        no: {
          text: "No",
          options: [{
            type: "message",
            text: "Call for help",
          }]
        }
      }]
    },
    no: {
      type: "question",
      text: "No",
      options: [{
        type: "question",
        text: "have you tried this other thing?",
        options: [
          `...`
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

Now `options[0].yes.options[0].yes.options[0].text` is `Can't help`.

Comment: That is not a bad idea at all. Thank you! I guess having different elements in the array can make it easier to navigate. I am going to investigate this for a while and see the possibilities